# List table size cutting off

Tags: sharepoint-online, webpart-width, list-webpart

Is there a way to change the size of a displayed list to full screen?

Currently my list has several columns that get cut off when viewing the list. SharePoint inserts a horizontal scroll but I would like to expand the default width.

Is this possible?

Update --

This is the only web part on the page.

Through more google foo I found that the issue is that TEAMS sites do not allow for "Full Width Column", is there a programmatic way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please add a screen shot, also are there any other web parts on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply custom code with Content Editor web part on the list page to trigger the "Focus on Content" mode when loading the list.

Please note that Content Editor web part is only available in classic experience.

[image]

Please see the sample script below.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function()
{
  SetFullScreenMode(true);
}
</script>
```

Resource: 
[Sharepoint 2013 - Fullscreen mode/hide quick launch.](http://technicaltrix.blogspot.com/2013/02/sharepoint-2013-fullscreen-modehide.html)

Comment: This looks like the answer I am looking for. However every time I attempt to edit a SP page I understand how much I dont know about SP. I do not see the Content Editor web part as an option. I looked into it an it appears to be available from the ribbon when editing a page. I do not have a ribbon and can not figure out how to make it appear. I looked into this as well and all answers are not consistent with what I see as options in SP. For example, one answer says to enable under site settings - navigation under look and feel. I have Navigation Elements under look & feel but no ribbon options.

Comment: @MrNiceGuy I have updated the reply with a gif, please see the procedure.

Comment: This will prove my SP inexperience but how do you get the tabs to show up? I've been through as many settings as I can find, and all my googling shows me answers with menu options that I dont have. For example, your GIF starts with you going to the settings cog and clicking edit page...edit page is not one of my options. I have "Edit" next to "Republish" but that does not show me any tabs.

Comment: Update, I just got off the phone with MSFT support. The "brilliant" SP engineers decided that the classic view has been removed from all pages except for the root site page. As I trying to edit a non root site the options you have given me are no longer available....ever. lol I am looking for a work around, maybe sharepoint designer will work.